# Cannot Access Variable Declared In Class From HTML Template Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

First, I know I should be using a service for this and plan to, but I wasn't able to retrieve the data in the service, so I built it in my component. I am unable to access the 'photos' variable from the html template. Getting error listed below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';
import {PhotosComponentComponent} from './photos-component/photos-    component.component';
import {PhotosServiceService} from './photos-component/photos-    service.service';
// import {photos} from './photos-component/photo';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ang2demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'ang2demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['ang2demo.component.css'],
  providers: [PhotosServiceService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]    
})

export class Ang2demoAppComponent {

  title = 'ang2demo works!';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}


  private photosUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

  getPhotos(){

   this.http.get(this.photosUrl)
    .map((res:Response, data) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        let photos = data;
        console.log(photos);
        return photos; //Now this variable 'photos' contains all of my data from the http.get request. But, I cannot access it from the template - Below
      }
    )
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPhotos()
  }
}
```

Here is my template code that is served in the templateUrl

```
<div ngIf *ngFor="let photo of photos">{{photo.url}}</div>
```

I receive an error that "cannot read url property of undefined." Why don't I have access to the photos variable from the template html?

Comment: You declared type of the variable but not initialized it. So it's undefined until you give it value. Your code looks good to me. Http call is async so photos will be filled when response is returned from the server. Is it still undefined after value assignment in the subscribe function?

Comment: If you paste 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos' in your browser, do you get back a json result?

Comment: Possibly this is because you have `this.photos<photos[]>` type.. And you are assigning `data` which is not `photos[]` type.

Comment: it is still undefined even after I step through the line data => {this.photos = data}. At that point, photos is still = undefined. Yes, this url returns json. I thought that I could assign data (which is a collection of arrays of json objects) to be of any type and photos is of type array, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

As your code is now, you are not saving the photos on the controller instance, and there by making it available to the template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let photo of photos">{{photo.url}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  photos: any[];
  private photosUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPhotos()
  }

  getPhotos() {
    this.http.get(this.photosUrl)
      .map(data => data.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.photos = data;
      });
  }
}
```

Here is a minimal [plunker demonstrating the code](https://plnkr.co/edit/QdvkpgFjgcPZjZ88i9ol?p=preview).

Comment: This is the solution I tried first, and it puts me back into the situation where when I reference this.photos = data, that photos is "undefined" and "this" is nolonger scoped to 'Ang2demoAppComponent' but ends up scoped to 'SafeSubscriber' which of course 'photos' does not exist. So, It's scoped properly up until it returns the data and then the scope has been changed.

Comment: What are the versions of TypeScript and Angular? I've added a plunker with the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with this. I removed this logic from the component and built it into a Service where I return a mapped Observable. I imported that into my component and made a reference to it from the ngOnInit function after declaring it in my constructor.

Then I used *ngFor to iterate the Observable and was still having issues, but when iterating an Observable you have to pipe with async " let photo of photos | async". After doing that, all works fine.

It looks like when calling the .subscribe method on an array, it returns its own scope which then replaces the reference of "this".